# Member Eligibility Continuity SQL Server code

Tags: sql-server, sap-iq

I have a set of data where a member comes in, enrolls into a plan for some time and after completion of his enrollment, if he wishes to continue he can enroll the next day or he can take a break for some time and enroll again, or he can totally terminate.

Sample Data:

```
Member  Start Date  End Date    Eligibility
1       1/1/1901    12/31/2009  N
1       1/1/2010    12/31/2010  Y
1       1/1/2011    12/31/2011  Y
1       1/1/2012    12/31/2012  N
1       1/1/2013    12/31/2013  Y
1       1/1/2014    12/31/2199  N
2       1/1/1901    12/31/2009  N
2       1/1/2010    12/31/2010  Y
2       1/1/2011    12/31/2011  Y
2       1/1/2012    12/31/2012  N
2       1/1/2013    12/31/2013  Y
2       1/1/2014    12/31/2199  N
```

I need all the continuous eligibility records to be combined into one single record and need the output:

```
Member  Start Date  End Date    Eligibility
1       1/1/1901    12/31/2009  N
1       1/1/2010    12/31/2011  Y
1       1/1/2012    12/31/2012  N
1       1/1/2013    12/31/2013  Y
1       1/1/2014    12/31/2199  N
2       1/1/1901    12/31/2009  N
2       1/1/2010    12/31/2011  Y
2       1/1/2012    12/31/2012  N
2       1/1/2013    12/31/2013  Y
2       1/1/2014    12/31/2199  N
```

Dates may vary for member to member and eligibilities too....

Please let me know the logic to write in SQL Server, Sybase IQ

Comment: This looks like a pretty typical gaps and islands type of query to me. Here is an excellent article that describes exactly what you are trying to do here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/71550/

Answer (score 0):

At least in SQL Server you can do this by using few tricks with row_number(), if you number the rows in the order of startdate and also order the rows in the order of eligibility, startdate, then if the difference between the two numbers is the same, the rows belong to the same range and can be combined. It can be done this way:

```
select Member, min(StartDate) as StartDate, max(EndDate) as EndDate, Eligibility
from
(
  select 
    *, row_number() over (partition by member order by Eligibility, startdate) - RN as GRP
  from
  (
    select
      *, row_number() over (partition by member order by startdate) as RN
    from
      table1
  ) X
) Y
group by Member, Eligibility, GRP
order by member, startdate
```

This assumes you have no gaps in your date ranges, which seems to be the case.

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dcb8b/1)